# Equal Polynomials - Similar Question that was closed.

Tags: polynomials

I saw a line recently on here that I found quite interesting, but it was closed. Was something along the lines of

Find all polynomials Q that satisfy the equation:
1/(Q(x) − 1) = Q(1/(x+1))

When I first saw this, I was thinking linear polynomials was a good start, and it seemed like they work. Not sure how if or how to prove they are the only polynomials that work though.

Thanks :)

Comment: That question was closed because the problem was just dumped here.

Comment: Now you know why such questions get closed. Where is the context? What did you try?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited. New to the platform so accidentally submitted early. Please take a look again, so sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, but still, what have you tried except linear polynomials? Aaah, now I see. It is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657503/find-fx-that-satisfies-f1-xfx-1-1-1) again. Write $X=x+1$. There was no context there, too.

Comment: I've mostly tried guessing some polynomials in hope of finding a pattern, but all I've found is linear polynomials. Not sure if that's going to be the answer, but I figured now was the time to try and start to do this rigorously. Tried shifting some stuff around, but didn't make much progress with that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think it was that one, just looked around and found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659317/equal-polynomials-help-on-where-to-start-please

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657503/find-fx-that-satisfies-f1-xfx-1-1-1) is exactly yours, writing $y=x+1$, so $1/Q(y)=1/(Q(y-1)-1)$. So you could read the comments and include it to your post (which is a duplicate of this one).

Comment: ohh i see, thanks. anything else you think I could try?

Comment: Oh, the other $14$ comments say more than I could say. It seems you haven't yet looked at them? Please do so and include it into your post, or it will be closed again.

Comment: Alright, sounds good.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is there a way to just port over the comments, or what did you mean for me to paraphrase?

Comment: I thought you could cite the comments, or summarise them, together with a link of this question. You still don't have a link to your former question.

Comment: You should also re-examine your claim that "linear polynomials" work. There are exactly two degree 0 polynomials, and a single degree 1 polynomial that satisfy the condition.

Comment: This is cheating, see [here](https://rossprogram.org/students/application-problems.pdf).